# Python, Requests: Help submitting a form on this website using Requests, Python

Tags: python, python-requests

I  am able to submit a form to capture individual page data on this website: www.asx.com.au

Typically, in the search bar you would enter a stock code (eg. 'WOW' for 'Woolworths') then click search, and get taken to that stock's page.

Here's the code I'm trying. Problem is, the form doesn't have a name, so I'm not sure how to reference it. Any help much appreciated:

```
import requests

url = 'https://www.asx.com.au/s/search.html'

payload = {'query':'WOW'}

r = requests.get(url, params=payload)

with open("requests_results.html","wb") as f:

    f.write(r.content)
```

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to Stackoverflow!

All you have to do is change your URL to `https://search.asx.com.au/s/search.html?query=WOW&collection=asx-meta&profile=web`, which is formed in the website while you search any term. Because the website uses `GET` method to pass data to form which accepts arguments by string parameters in URL itself (`?query=WOW&collection=asx-meta&profile=web`).

So the code will be like,

```
import requests
url = 'https://search.asx.com.au/s/search.html?query=WOW&collection=asx-meta&profile=web'
with open("requests_results.html","wb") as f:
    f.write(requests.get(url).content)
```

Cheers!

Comment: Hey SmashGuy, thanks for the welcome and the quick response!

Comment: Is there a way I can pass the stock code into the argument, so I can set up a loop to pull in the data for more than one stock code?

Answer (score 0):

Found how to pass in things to construct the URL using Requests (under 'Passing Parameters into URLs'): http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/

> > > payload = {'key1': 'value1', 'key2': 'value2'}
> > >       r = requests.get('http://httpbin.org/get', params=payload)